# When the summation is equal to factorial and primorial products?

Tags: summation, factorial, primorial

Is it known when the summation is equal to factorial ?

$$
n! = \sum_{i=1}^{m}i = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}
$$

where $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$

$$
3! = \sum_{i=1}^{3}i = 6 
$$

$$
5! = \sum_{i=1}^{15}i = 120
$$

And also when product of primes is equal to summation:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i = \sum_{i=1}^{m}i
$$

where $P_n$ is the $n$th prime and $m \in \mathbb{N}$

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{2}P_i = 2\times3 = \sum_{i=1}^{2}i = 6 
$$

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{4}P_i = 2\times3\times5\times7 = \sum_{i=1}^{20}i = 210
$$

I was not able to find other pairs of factorial and primorial which are equals to summation.

I would like to know how to prove that other pairs either exist or doesn't exist.

Comment: Looking at the discriminant of $$n^2+n-2a=0$$ we see that an integer solution exists if and only if $\ 8a+1\ $ is a perfect square. It seems that the only factorials satisfying this are $1!,3!$ and $5!$. Upto $(10^4)!$ , there is no further example.

Comment: In the case of the primorials, a further example seems to exist neither. The largest prime in the product must exceed $10^5$ for a further example.

Comment: Look here: http://www.shyamsundergupta.com/factorial.htm

Comment: @Peter how do we know that there is no other perfect squares for $8a+1$  with $a < (10^4)!$ and in case of primorial from where $10^5$ boundaries for largest prime came from?

Comment: I checked them with PARI/GP